# Calling DATE_FORMAT() in MySQL from Django fails

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-python

I can run `SET` statements to assign variables and use "transaction" to maintain it in the mySQL session, but when I include the function `DATE_FORMAT` like this:

```
cursor.execute("SET @dowToday:=CAST( DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%w' ) AS UNSIGNED);")
```

Django complains that

> not enough arguments for format string in /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py in execute, line 151

It doesn't help to remove the CAST or to play with or escape the quotes.

Thoughts?

Comment: My guess is that it's the `%` percent sign in the SQL text. Maybe Django is expecting that is bind variable placeholder. Either that, or Django is running some `sprintf` style function, and expecting that the `%w` is a placeholder that is supposed to be replaced with some argument value. Maybe there's a way to "escape" the `%` so that Django ignors it, and passes it to MySQL as a literal. (I haven't tested, this is really just a guess.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally missed the point in my previous answer. This is a Django cursor. Not a "standard Python" one.

According to the doc:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

> Note that if you want to include literal percent signs in the query,
> you have to double them in the case you are passing parameters:
>
> ```
> cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = '30%%' and id = %s", [self.id])
> ```

I assume if this does not work, your could fallback to some simple-and-stupid trick:

```
cursor.execute("SET @dowToday:=CAST( DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%sw' ) AS UNSIGNED);", ['%'])
```

The `%s` will be replaced by the `%` passed as an argument...

Comment: Thanks, While using %s or \% didn't work, using a double percent resolved it.  
`cursor.execute("SET @dowToday:=CAST( DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%%w' ) AS UNSIGNED);")`

Comment: @IMStarboard ... hum ... I'm very disappointed that that "%s" trick didn't work :( Anyway, the `%%` is the recommended way, and it is great it worked for you :D

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the issue is with the percent sign (`%`) in the query text. (Isn't that a bind variable placeholder in Django?) e.g. if we were going to use a bind variable, wouldn't that look something like this?

```
SELECT 'foo' FROM DUAL WHERE 'a' = %(varname)s ;
```

I think maybe Django is scanning your SQL text and encountering `%w` and expecting that to be a bind variable. Either that, or it's running an `sprintf` style function, and encountering the `%w` and expecting to replace that placeholder with an argument value.

(I haven't tested; so this is just an idea, just a guess.)

As a guess to a workaround, maybe you double up the percent signs, the same we get % literals through an sprintf:

```
  query("SELECT ... ,'%%w') ...");
```

If that doesn't work, then maybe it's a backslash character, the same we escape characters in a regular expression:

```
  query("SELECT ... ,'\%w') ...");
```

(Or, you might need to double up the backslashes. These are just guesses based on conventions used by other software.)

Comment: I don't have a workaround, I'm just guessing. But I'd be looking for a way to either "escape" that `'%'` so that Django ignores it (maybe double up the percents `%%` sprintf style, or use a backslash `\%`? (based solely on experience with conventions used by other software). Either that, or I'd be looking for a way to disable Django for scanning for placeholders (sqlplus style SET SCAN OFF). Not much help from me, in the way of a workaround. Sorry.

Comment: The second answer in this suggests doubling up the % sign %% to get the % literal passed. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770620/django-raw-query-percent-sign-problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770620/django-raw-query-percent-sign-problem)  (I don't see how the selected answer to the question helps anything Django-wise... or maybe both work. (The `foo LIKE '\%'` is how we'd get MySQL to match a literal %, and for MySQL not to interpret the % as a wildcard match. But that doesn't address the issue of getting a literal percent sign slipped past Django.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the error is produced by *that* call?

---

Looking at the code of `cursor.py` on my system, that leads to:

```
def execute(self, query, args=None):

    # ...

    if isinstance(query, unicode):
        query = query.encode(charset)
    if args is not None:
        query = query % db.literal(args)         # Line 151
```

According to that, this exception could only be thrown if `args` is not `None` -- which seems impossible considering the call:

```
cursor.execute("SET @dowToday:=CAST( DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%w' ) AS UNSIGNED);")
```

Comment: I know it seems crazy, but here is another example that throws the same error:

cursor.execute("SELECT DATE_FORMAT( created_at, '%w' ) FROM discussion_posts limit 2")

Comment: Also should mention that if I replace that one line with a different statement that does not include the DATE_FORMAT function it works