# Passing literal percent sign to QuerySet.extra()

Tags: python, django, sqlite, python-3.x, django-1.7

I’d like to execute the following code:

```
 Booking.objects.filter(start_ts__isnull = False, end_ts__isnull = False).extra(select = {'amount': "strftime('%s', end_ts) - strftime('%s', start_ts)"})
```

However, in the shell, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/polesz/Projects/duckbook/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 835, in extra
    clone.query.add_extra(select, select_params, where, params, tables, order_by)
  File "/home/polesz/Projects/duckbook/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1744, in add_extra
    entry_params.append(next(param_iter))
StopIteration
```

I have tried doubling the percent signs (`%%s`) and escaping them with a backslash (`\%s`), but neither helped. I also looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18143147/1305139), but that solution doesn’t work with `QuerySet.extra()` (or I just miss the point).

What is the correct way to solve this?

**Edit**: I also tried to use `select_params` like this:

```
Booking.objects.filter(start_ts__isnull = False, end_ts__isnull = False).extra(select = {'amount': "strftime('%s', end_ts) - strftime(%s, start_ts)"}, select_params = ['%s', '%s'])
```

but regardless the usage of quote signs, the resulting query has `\'%s\'`, which gives an SQL error, of course.

Comment: Did u get to know the answer of this question? If yes the please post the correct answer of this question.

Comment: Not yet, but I’m still interested (even though the project has moved to PostgreSQL by now).

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, and wanted to follow up here.

I got around this issue by using the .format method with double percent signs. For example, if you had a `Foo` model with `date_field` and wanted to perform a SQL method `date_format(date_field, '%Y-%m')`, you can do it in Django 1.7 ORM this way:

```
Foo.objects.extra(
    select={'formatted_date': 
        "date_format(date_field, '{param}')".format(param='%%Y-%%m')}
)
```

For your reference, there's a bug in Django 1.7 where passing literal `%s` to extra select directly was not allowed. This has since been fixed, and here's the link: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23460